# How to add the parameter when calling the function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to call a function which has a param, I am using arrow functions.

Just an example:

```
_openAddDealer = (dealerInfo) => {
  console.log(dealerInfo);
}
```

And I need to call that from a button

```
<FloatingActionButton onClick={this._openAddDealer}>
```

For the rest of the functions I don't need any bind to `this` or something similar. So, what can I do to something like this:

```
<FloatingActionButton onClick={this._openAddDealer(dealerInfo)}>
```

I tried like that but the function is being called when the app loads and not when the button is pressed.

Comment: This isn't really an ES6 issue, is it? You're binding a parameter to a function, in any ES*.

Comment: @Rudie can you explain it in an answer ? please.

Comment: Where is `dealerInfo` coming from where you call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is JSX. Likely you're looking for something like:

```
<FloatingActionButton onClick={() => this._openAddDealer(dealerInfo)}>
```

Comment: Philosophically speaking: AWESOME !

Comment: Great! This is JSX, right? Let's tag it that way and tighten up the title.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be this simple:

```
button.onClick = function() {
  // with button's this
  _openAddDealer.call(this, dealerInfo);
  // with outside this
  _openAddDealer(dealerInfo);
};
```

? I don't know what you're doing with the `<` etc, so I might misunderstand...

Comment: did not get the button.onClick. I just did `<FloatingActionButton onClick={this._openAddDealer.call(this, dealerInfo)}>` and the same happens.